# Thunderbird keeps prompting for google password

Tags: thunderbird, google, calendar

Why does Thunderbird keep asking me for my google password and then reject my password when I enter it?

It is connecting to my g-mail account without any problem. This seems to be when it tries to get access to my google calendar.

Comment: Although this is probably not your issue, I want to mention that this happens when you make more than the maximum amount of IMAP connections to a Google account (currently 10).

Answer (score 7):

There is a problem with the google calendar sync app, and you were recently downgraded to 0.3.2 - you should be at 1.0.2  You can find the correct version at [this link](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/), or perhaps by now you can go through the add-on section of Thunderbird to fix this.

If you use the link, you can download the add-on to disk, and in Thunderbirds add-on menu choose install add-on from file.  Thunderbird will need to be restarted, but works much better afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Green, updating the add-on manually solved the problem. I was wondering: isn't this add-on also provided by the `xul-ext-gdata-provider` Ubuntu package? I tried to distil the version number and compare it to the add on from the Mozilla website, but the package version is 1:31.2.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04, which doesn't seem to relate to either 0.32 or 1.0.2.

Comment: I believe it does, but then Thunderbird handles the job of keeping the add-ons updated:  There was (not my words, but what I read) a problem with the Google API which caused the older version to load over version 1.0.2  I just loaded `xul-ext-gdata-provider` in my test Ubuntu (VM) and it was version 0.3.2

Comment: You can't uninstall the old "Provider for Google Calendar 0.32" add-on. Instead, disable the old add-on, download `provider_for_google_calendar-1.0.2-tb+sm.xpi` using the above link.  Then, install by clicking on the icon next to the "Search all add-ons" text field, and select "Install Add-on From File...".  Your existing calendars will be removed from Thunderbird, once you install the new add-on.  However, you are actually able to select and add your existing Google calendars, once Thunderbird restarts, which is a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a launchpad bug regarding this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1465524

There is an old package that is going to be installed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with my contact sync.

Turned out the problem was using the outdated add-on "Google Contacts" (last updated in 2013) to sync my gmail-contacts, which failed since google changed its API.

Replacing it with [gContactSync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/gcontactsync/) (v. 2.0.5) solved the problem for now. It seems to be well maintained.